# How to stop repo:push if webhooks condition fails in BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, jira, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-cloud

I'm trying to stop the repo push in Bitbucket if the commit statement doesn't have the defined Jira issue id in the remark. 
I have successfully invoked the URL for checking the commit remark via webhooks but unable to figure out the way to stop the push in case of failure.

Comment: You can't stop the push once it's on bitbucket, instead you must stop it before it gets to bitbucket. See @EdmundDipple's answer.

Comment: Yes, @evolutionxbox I meant to stop it from getting before to bitbucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customise the following script from this example of a `msg-commit` git hook.

```
#!/bin/bash

MSG="$1"

if ! grep -qE "updated" "$MSG";then
    cat "$MSG"
    echo "Your commit message must contain the word 'updated'"
    exit 1
fi
```

Check this code into git, and then run

```
# give the script "execute" permission
chmod 755 commit-msg
# put the script in the correct place
cp commit-msg .git/hooks/commit-msg
```

If you try and create a commit without the word 'updated' in the message, then this hook will prevent the commit from being created successfully.

Source: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

> The `commit-msg hook` takes one parameter, which again is the path to a temporary file that contains the commit message written by the developer. If this script exits non-zero, Git aborts the commit process, so you can use it to validate your project state or commit message before allowing a commit to go through. In the last section of this chapter, We’ll demonstrate using this hook to check that your commit message is conformant to a required pattern.

Note that anyone else who clones your repository will also need to copy the hook into `.git/hooks/commit-msg`

Answer (score 1):

For your particular use case:

> stop the repo push in Bitbucket if the commit statement doesn't have the defined Jira issue id in the remark

It has been added to Bitbucket Cloud as a feature: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/link-to-a-web-service/#Require-linked-issue-keys-in-commits

All you need to do is toggle it on.